# Lim Sup/Inf for real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, functions

To understand the notion of, say, limit superior for a sequence, is not difficult. Simply consider the set of all upper buonds for the set of all limit points of the sequence, and then simply pick the inf of this set.
I said simply, because for a sequence, we only take limits to infinity.

Now, for a function we can calculate limits to any point.

So, what exactly means $$\limsup_{x\to c} f(x) $$

Wikipedia is unclear about this, and I found nothing in my (tiny) literature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The supremum is the least upper bound on $f(x)$. Therefore by definition of limit we have that it is least upper bound on a point. I think that it only exists if $\textup{lim} \  \ textup{sup} f(x)= \textup{lim} \ \textup{sup} f(c)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is defined as

$$ \underset{x \to a}{\mbox{lim sup}} f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} (\sup \{f(x) : x \in B(a,\epsilon) \setminus \{a\}\})$$

Comment: But if epsilon tends to zero, this appears to be precisely the regular limit...

Comment: If the limit exists, this will give the same value. But the lim sup exists even if the limit does not. For example, consider the function that is $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals. The lim sup of this function as you approach $0$ is $1$, and the lim inf is $0$, but no limit exists.

Comment: I'm starting to understand. Can you give me some example involving semicontinuity?

Comment: Can you clarify that? What do you mean by semicontinuity, I don't see how general semicontinuity relates to this.

Comment: See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition. Thanks again

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Well, take Wikipedia's picture example of an upper-semicontinuous function. Clearly, the limit doesn't exist. However, as you shrink the neighborhoods around the point where the discontinuity lies, you see that the supremum goes to the right-hand limit, so that is the lim sup. Symmetrically, the left-hand limit is the lim inf.

Comment: Hi. Only works for $a<\infty$? What about the $lim sup f(x)$ as $x$ goes to infty? Is this question relevant?